# whats does あなたわ友達ですか？ means

Tags: grammar, meaning

So I have recently have gotten into japanese and my close friend who is from japan is teaching me japenese, one of the sentence she wrote is this あなたわ友達ですか？ which I sort of understand and I know is refering to me, but eventually I don't have the knowledge to put it all together yet, if anyone could help it would be nice

Comment: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

Comment: It means that the writer is a beginner at Japanese. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well really I would be assuming he meant " Are you my friend?" or " you're my friend? "  although the sentence should really be あなたは友達ですか and even that translation is a bit generic but yes that's what he must have meant. 
あなた　(formal) you
は　topic marker particle　( not spelled わ )
友達　friend
です　formal/polite particle basically meaning being etc
か　formal/polite question particle